# Android - ArrayList não está sendo preenchido

Tags: android, lista, arraylist

Eu criei um código com uma classe Contato

```
public class Contato {
    private String nome;
    private Integer foto;
    private String ramal;
    private String setor;
    private String email;

    public Contato(String nome, Integer foto, String ramal, String setor, String email) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.foto = foto;
        this.ramal = ramal;
        this.setor = setor;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public static Contato[] contatos = {
            new Contato("Fulano", R.drawable.fulano,"7145", "TI", "fulano@teste.com.br"),
            new Contato("Ciclano", R.drawable.ciclano,"7144", "Comercial", "ciclano@teste.com.br"),
    };

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public Integer getFoto() {
        return foto;
    }

    public void setFoto(Integer foto) {
        this.foto = foto;
    }

    public String getRamal() {
        return ramal;
    }

    public void setRamal(String ramal) {
        this.ramal = ramal;
    }

    public String getSetor() {
        return setor;
    }

    public void setSetor(String setor) {
        this.setor = setor;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

Então criei outra classe onde os valores são pegos de uma tela e devem ser enviados para esse ArrayList e quando o botão é pressionado, atualizando os itens da RecyclerView.

```
public class CadastroFragment extends Fragment {

    View view;

    EditText newNome;
    EditText newRamal;
    EditText newEmail;

    String nome;
    String ramal;
    String email;
    String setor;
    String[] setoresSpinner;

    private Spinner setores;

    public CadastroFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cadastro, container, false);

        newNome = view.findViewById(R.id.new_Nome);
        newEmail = view.findViewById(R.id.new_Email);
        newRamal = view.findViewById(R.id.new_Ramal);
        setores = view.findViewById(R.id.new_setor);

        setoresSpinner = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sectors);
        setores.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(), R.layout.spinner_adapter, setoresSpinner));

        Button cadastrar = view.findViewById(R.id.new_cadastro);
        cadastrar.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener(){
                    public void onClick(View view){
                        nome = newNome.getText().toString();
                        email = newEmail.getText().toString();
                        ramal = newRamal.getText().toString();
                        setor = setores.getSelectedItem().toString();

                        List<Contato> listaContato = new ArrayList<Contato>();
                        listaContato.add(new Contato(nome, R.drawable.logo, ramal, setor, email));
                    }
                }

        );

        return view;
    }

}
```

Meu Adapter:

```
public class MyFirstAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyFirstAdapter.MyFirstViewHolder> {
    private List<Contato> contatoList;
    private MyOnItemClickListener myOnItemClickListener;
    private View itemView;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyFirstViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, final int viewType) {
        itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.contatos_layout, viewGroup,false);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
            if (myOnItemClickListener != null){
                TextView txt = view.findViewById(R.id.contato_nome);
                myOnItemClickListener.myOnItemClick(txt.getText().toString());
            }
            }
        });
        final MyFirstViewHolder holder = new MyFirstViewHolder(itemView);

        itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                contatoList.remove(holder.position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                return true;
            }
        });


        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyFirstViewHolder myFirstViewHolder, final int position) {
            myFirstViewHolder.onBind(contatoList.get(position), position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return contatoList.size();
    }

    class MyFirstViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ImageView contatoFoto;
        TextView contatoNome;
        TextView contatoRamal;
        TextView contatoEmail;
        TextView contatoSetor;
        int position;
        public MyFirstViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            contatoFoto = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contato_foto);
            contatoNome = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contato_nome);
            contatoRamal = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contato_ramal);
            contatoEmail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contato_email);
            contatoSetor = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contato_setor);
        }

        public void onBind(Contato contato, int pos){
            position = pos;
            contatoNome.setText(contato.getNome());
            contatoRamal.setText(Html.fromHtml(contato.getRamal()));
            contatoFoto.setImageResource(contato.getFoto());
            contatoEmail.setText(contato.getEmail());
            contatoSetor.setText(contato.getSetor());
        }

    }

    public interface MyOnItemClickListener{
        void myOnItemClick(String nome);
    }


    public MyFirstAdapter(List<Contato> contatoList){
        this.contatoList = contatoList;
    }

    public void setMyOnItemClickListener(MyOnItemClickListener myOnItemClickListener){
        this.myOnItemClickListener = myOnItemClickListener;
    }
}
```

O problema é que minha RecyclerView não está sendo atualizada, como se meu código não estivesse inserindo os novos cadastros na ArrayList.

Comment: Oi amigo.... eu gostaria de ajudar você mas eu preciso ver o código completo da classe onde você insere os dados na sua recyclerView.... Por isso, peço que você reedite com o código completo da classe para meu melhor entendimento....

Comment: Observe! eu preciso ver a classe inteira onde você insere os novos dados (A classe do botão) e não o Adapter do recyclerView

Comment: Atualizado coma classe inteira

Comment: Tá, mas como que você está fazendo para settar a sua lista no recyclerView?

Comment: Você está usando ``adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`` depois de inserir um novo item no recyclerView?

Comment: Como que posso settar e onde utilizar o notifyDataSetChanged? Sou novo nisso e pensei que era só criar um novo Contato que ele iria inserir na lista. Prefere que eu atualize com meu Adapter?

Comment: Então para criar um recyclerView e inserir dados nele, você tem que criar um construtor, um adapter do construtor para o recyclerView e uma lista do construtor para configurar no adapter do recyclerView..... Eu não posso te ensinar isso aqui porque é muito trabalhoso, mas você pode pesquisar como criar um "recyclerView no Android Studio (Se você usa Android Studio)" no youtube. Tem muito tutoria lá e você pega o conceito rapidinho....

Comment: Observe! O RecyclerView é ideal para configurar listas muito grande, pois a responsabilidade atribuída a ele é muito menor do do que em um listView. Entretanto, se seu aplicativo tiver uma lista pequena, use um listView ao invés do recyclerView, pois este é muito mais fácil de lidar.

Comment: Um exemplo disto é que no listView você pode selecionar um item da sua lista usando o método ``setOnItemClickListiner`` e no recyclerView você vai ter que criar uma interface para poder selecionar um item da lista e isto é muito mais trabalhoso.

Comment: O Recycler view está funcionando, aqueles dois contatos aparecem, o problema é que quando vou usar o botão para inserir novos contatos, minha recyclerview continua exibindo só os antigos, ela não atualiza.

Comment: Dá uma olhadinha na minha resposta....

Comment: Pronto.....Ruan

Answer (score 0):

Dá uma olhadinha. Acho que o problema é que você não estava fazendo o adapter da lista para o recyclerView.

```
public class CadastroFragment extends Fragment {

    View view;

    EditText newNome;
    EditText newRamal;
    EditText newEmail;

    String nome;
    String ramal;
    String email;
    String setor;
    String[] setoresSpinner;

    private Spinner setores;

    /*

    Você precisa criar um Adapter para configurar a sua lista no seu recyclerView

    */

    private Adapter<MyFirstAdapter> adapter;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;



    public CadastroFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cadastro, container, false);

        List<Contato> listaContato = new ArrayList<Contato>(); //code:(1)

        //Recupere o devido ID do recyclerView e inicie o adapter. Veja abaixo;

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.seuRecyclerView);
        adapter = new MyFirstAdapter(getContext(),listaContato,CadastroFragment.this);
            //(Você instancia o adapter com os dois contatos pré definidos no seu costrutror)// 
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        newNome = view.findViewById(R.id.new_Nome);
        newEmail = view.findViewById(R.id.new_Email);
        newRamal = view.findViewById(R.id.new_Ramal);
        setores = view.findViewById(R.id.new_setor);

        setoresSpinner = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sectors);
        setores.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(), R.layout.spinner_adapter, setoresSpinner));

        Button cadastrar = view.findViewById(R.id.new_cadastro);
        cadastrar.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener(){
                    public void onClick(View view){
                        nome = newNome.getText().toString();
                        email = newEmail.getText().toString();
                        ramal = newRamal.getText().toString();
                        setor = setores.getSelectedItem().toString();

                        // Instacie a lista fora do envento de click. Veja lá em cima em code:(1)
                        listaContato.add(new Contato(nome, R.drawable.logo, ramal, setor, email));

                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            //(Você atualiza seu adapter mostando o novo valor adcionado)//
                    }
                }

        );

        return view;
    }

}
```

---

**[ADICIONADO]**

```
public class MyFirstAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyFirstAdapter.MyFirstViewHolder> {


    private List<Contato> contatoList;
    private MyOnItemClickListener myOnItemClickListener;
    private View itemView;

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Constructor_Bula> mData ;
    private List<Constructor_Bula> mDataFiltered ;
    private ContactsAdapterListener listener;



    public interface ContactsAdapterListener {
        void onContactSelected(Constructor_Bula construtorBula);
    }

    MyFirstAdapter(Context mContext, List<Contato> mContatoList, ContactsAdapterListener listener) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.contatoList = mContatoList;
        this.listener = listener;

    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyFirstViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, final int viewType) {

        itemView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.contatos_layout, viewGroup,false);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
            if (myOnItemClickListener != null){
                TextView txt = view.findViewById(R.id.contato_nome);
                myOnItemClickListener.myOnItemClick(txt.getText().toString());
            }
            }
        });
        final MyFirstViewHolder holder = new MyFirstViewHolder(itemView);

        itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                contatoList.remove(holder.position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                return true;
            }
        });


        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyFirstViewHolder myFirstViewHolder, final int position) {
            myFirstViewHolder.onBind(contatoList.get(position), position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return contatoList.size();
    }

    class MyFirstViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ImageView contatoFoto;
        TextView contatoNome;
        TextView contatoRamal;
        TextView contatoEmail;
        TextView contatoSetor;
        int position;
        public MyFirstViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            contatoFoto = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contato_foto);
            contatoNome = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contato_nome);
            contatoRamal = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contato_ramal);
            contatoEmail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contato_email);
            contatoSetor = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contato_setor);
        }

        public void onBind(Contato contato, int pos){
            position = pos;
            contatoNome.setText(contato.getNome());
            contatoRamal.setText(Html.fromHtml(contato.getRamal()));
            contatoFoto.setImageResource(contato.getFoto());
            contatoEmail.setText(contato.getEmail());
            contatoSetor.setText(contato.getSetor());
        }

    }

    public interface MyOnItemClickListener{
        void myOnItemClick(String nome);
    }


    public MyFirstAdapter(List<Contato> contatoList){
        this.contatoList = contatoList;
    }

    public void setMyOnItemClickListener(MyOnItemClickListener myOnItemClickListener){
        this.myOnItemClickListener = myOnItemClickListener;
    }
}
```

Você vai precisar modificar um pouco o seu Adaper. No caso, você precisa criar um construtor para receber o contexto, a lista e o evento de click no item. Mas neste último, parece que você já o faz no próprio adapter entã só considere os dois primeiros....

Observe!!!

NÃO ALTERE NADA NA SUA CLASSE, FAÇA ESTES TESTE EM UMA CLASSE SEPARADA, POIS SE O TESTE NÃO FUNCIONAR VOCÊ NÃO PERDE O QUE JÁ FEZ!!!

Então sugiro que para estes testes, crie uma classe chamada `MyFirstAdapter2.class` e insira os respectivos código lá e no fragmento instancie esta classe de teste....

Comment: Quando crio o private Adapter<MyFirstAdapter> adapter; ele dá erro "Cannot resolve symbol Adapter

Comment: Estranho, o private Adapter<MyFirstAdapter> adapter; diz que o <MyFirstAdapter> does not have type parameters